# Find the minimum of stand normal random variable and other probability problems

Tags: probability

**1.Suppose X is a standard normal random variable and**

**$g(x)=P(X<=x^2)$**

**(1)Find min g(x)**

**(2)Find $g'(1).$**

I know a standard normal random variable is
$P(Y<y) = 1/(2pi)^{1/2}\int_{-\infty}^{y}e^{-t^2/2}dt$
so I have change my upper bound y to x^2 in my integral, but how to calculate this function? I use wolfram alpha and get this [pic4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3xgE.png)
 it seems to me that's not what I want ...

**2.Find the variance of H with PDF**

**$f(h)=e^{-2|h|}$**

I know a PDF's expected value can calculate by  $E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x f(x) dx}$
,so my $E[h] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{he^{-2|h|} dh}$ = $2\int_{0}^{\infty}{he^{-2h} dh}$

I get $E[h] = 1/2$ and $E[h^2] = 1$
so $var(h) = 1/2$ is that correct?

**3.There are 3 coins.**

**If coin 1 is flipped, the probability of head is 0.3. If coin 2
is flipped, the probability of head is 0.5. If coin 3 is flipped, the probability of head
is 0.3. A coin is chosen with equal probability and flipped. If it is head, the next coin
(in cyclic order) is flipped twice. If it is tail, the other coin is flipped twice.**

**• Find the mean of the number of heads in 3 flips.**

**• Find the variance of the number of heads in 3 flips.**

I have no idea how to solve problem 3 ..

**UPDATE**

[pic5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgAJL.png)

ok I can get min value 0.5 of problem 1.1 but how can I get this value by pen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to Problem 2 looks fine to me.

Problem 3 is straightforward since there are only 3 coins.

Hint:

Say, coin1 is chosen first. This event happens with a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$. The chance of getting 3 heads $H_1H_2H_2$ is 0.3*0.5*0.5. Similarly, you can also calculate the probability of getting 2 heads $T_1H_3H_3$ is 0.3*0.3*0.3

Repeat this process if coin2 is chosen first and coin3 is chosen first.

Mean of number of heads would be $\frac{1}{3} (0.3*0.5*0.5 *3 +  0.3*0.3*0.3*2) + \text{simialrly terms obtained for coin2 and coin3} $

For problem 1, think of $g(X)$ has the CDF with a modified x-axis. Here the minimum absolute value that on the x-axis is zero. Think of what happens to the probability value if x is too large (it goes to one). If x is too close to zero, then probability value is 0.5. For the second part, try using [Leibniz rule.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Edit:

Some details on Problem 1: 
I think the confusion is because of $x$ and $X$. So, just replace $x$ with $t$.

$g(t) = P(X < t^2)$ is the probability that any randomly chosen value from the standard normal distribution is less than $t^2$. Note that $g(t)$ is *NOT* a random variable, rather it is a deterministic function with a unique value for each value of $t$

$g(0) = P(X< 0)$ which is 0.5 because the $X$ follows a standard normal and probability of $X$ being less than zero is 0.5. For any value $t>0$, $g(t) = P(X < t^2)$ which will be greater than $g(0)$. Hence, the minimum value is 0.5

$g(t)$ is an even function. So, it is symmetric about the $Y$-axis with minimum value at $t = 0$. It is also a smooth function. At a minimum, the derivative vanishes so $g^{'}(0) = 0$.

However, finding $g^{'}(1)$ is not so easy. Hence, you need to apply the Leibniz rule.

Comment: Problem 3 also have $H_1T_2H_2$ or $H_1H_2T_2$ .... isn't it? and I still can't understand about you said on problem1

Comment: Yeah.. those combinations as well

Comment: Can you give more details or give a example for problem 1? thank you

Comment: @achicn3 Updated.

Comment: Thank you , this is really clear and understandable... I really appreciated it.